# Azure Cognitive: Supplied language not supported

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to feed some simple, hello-worldish JSON samples to Azure's Cognitive Text Analysis; using this test data:

```
{
 "documents": [
     {
         "language": "it",
         "id": "1",
         "text": "<sample text in italian>"
     }
 ]}
```

The response is:

```
{
"documents":[],
"errors":[
{
    "id":"1",
    "message":"Supplied language not supported. Pass in one of: en,ja,de,es"
}
]}
```

This is unexpected because, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/overview#supported-languages Italian should be supported even in preview mode.

Comment: Which specific service are you calling? Please edit your question to show your `POST`. Italian is only supported with sentiment.

Comment: I'm calling https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/keyPhrases, so the key phrases service. I've missed to see that only sentiment is supported, so the fault was on my part. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just to close this out properly: While Italian (`"it"`) *is* a supported language with Text Analytics, it's currently only available for Sentiment, not Key Phrases or Topics.